# could ng-include block my CSS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to split up my HUGE main.html page into smaller parts so it will be better maintainable. It seems that ng-include is the way to go since i'm using angular already.

I'm not sure, but as soon as I use ng-include it seems the CSS of my website seems to fail... there's no error in the Crome console

Here's my main.html

```
<div ng-include src="'AddRegion.html'"></div>
    <div class="addbutton">                         
        <a href="#addregion_form" id="addregion_pop">ADD</a>                        
    </div>
```

and here is my AddRegions.html

```
<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="addregion_form"></a>
<div class="popup">
    <h2>Add Region</h2>
    <a class="closeBut" href="Main.html#close" ng-click="showAdminMenuContainer()"></a>
</div>
```

I already tried putting the code within the divs, i also tried adding the ng-include on top of the main.html like:

```
<ng-include src="'AddRegion.html'"></ng-include>
```

But that doesn't seem to work for me. The files are in the root, so no folder problems, Crome is not giving any errors in the console.

Comment: Whether `ng-include` interferes with your CSS depends a lot on the CSS too. (But to answer the title question, **YES**, the `ng-include` could block the CSS somehow.) A minimal complete verifiable example (JSFiddle?) would greatly help you get the help you need.

Comment: If your css is failing then you need to include some of the failing css in your question: it is possible you have css rules that simply don't match the changed html.
Also ng-include may not be the way to go: consider breaking up your html file by writing angular directives or components. That should give you much better control over the structure.

Comment: By the way, and irrelevant ot the question itself, if you are to refactor the huge HTML, do consider directives over `ng-include` :)